# Automated Trigger.IO deployment possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, trigger.io, ipa

Is there a way to script the packaging in the trigger.io toolkit?

My goal is to create a jenkins task for creating fresh e.g. ipa's for every revision. Is it possible to call a specific URL for running this packaging process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform some tasks through a command line tool included with the Toolkit for exactly this purpose.

Check out http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/commands.html in our docs for more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! How can a package iOS packages only? Is it possible? Assuming "forge package" builds packages for all platforms!?

Comment: you can run "forge build ios" then "forge package ios", to build and package for ios only.